# Why Views Data relationship between custom entity type and node doesn't work?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

Fields names are equal in both tables.

Inside [hook_views_data](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7):

```
  $data['stream']['table']['join'] = array(
    'node' => array(
      'left_field' => 'nid',
      'field' => 'nid',
    ),
  );

 $data['stream']['nid'] = array(
    'title' => t('Related node'),
    'help' => t('Node related to stream item.'),
    // Define a relationship to the {node} table, so example_table views can
    // add a relationship to nodes. If you want to define a relationship the
    // other direction, use hook_views_data_alter(), or use the 'implicit' join
    // method described above.
    'relationship' => array(
      'base' => 'node', // The name of the table to join with.
      'base field' => 'nid', // The name of the field on the joined table.
      'field' => 'nid',
      'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
      'label' => t('Default label for the relationship'),
      'title' => t('Title shown when adding the relationship'),
      'help' => t('More information on this relationship'),
    ),
  );
```

(similar to example from api page)

but there isn't above relation in Add relationships box. Could some one give me any hint?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by this way:

```
$data['stream']['table']['join'] = array(
  'node' => array(
    'left_field' => 'nid',
    'field' => 'nid',
    'handler' => 'views_join', // this is actually optional
    'left_table' => 'node'
  ),
);


$data['stream']['nid'] = array(
    'title' => t('Related node'),
    'help' => t('Node related to stream item.'),

    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),

    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
      'allow empty' => TRUE,
      'help' => 'Filter on a related node nid.',
    ),
    'argument' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_numeric',
      'numeric' => TRUE,
      'validate type' => 'nid',
      'help' => 'Argument on related node nid.',
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
      'help' => 'Sort on related node nid field.',
    ),
    'relationship' => array(
      'title' => t('Stream node'),
      'help' => t('Relation to node related to current stream item'),
      'label' => t('Stream node'),
      'base' => 'node',
      'base field' => 'nid',
    ),
  );
```